# VBA- Check if a particular userform is Loaded or not

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to check if a userform is loaded or not while running a code. I tried several ways, no-one is working. I remember I did that before, but I can't recall my workaround. Any idea?

I found some solutions here and other places, they also was not working!

The issues are …

1. vba.userforms just accepts index numbers, not string indexes,
2. on a loop over the userforms some properties like name is not accessible to check!

Here are my Tries:

```
Public Function IsFormVisible(FrmName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo errorH
    IsFormVisible = False
    Set Frm = UserForms(FrmName)
    If Not Frm Is Nothing Then IsFormVisible = True
    End Function
errorH:
    IsFormVisible = False
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function IsFormVisible(FrmName As String) As Boolean
Dim Frm As UserForm
On Error GoTo errorH
    IsFormVisible = False
    For Each Frm In VBA.UserForms
        If Frm.Name = FrmName Then
           IsFormVisible = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
errorH:
    IsFormVisible = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two simple options. First, you could declare `frm` as `Object`:

```
Public Function IsFormVisible(FrmName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Frm As Object
On Error GoTo errorH
    IsFormVisible = False
    For Each Frm In VBA.UserForms
        If LCase$(Frm.Name) = LCase$(FrmName) Then
           IsFormVisible = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
errorH:
    IsFormVisible = False
End Function
```

Or second, you could use `TypeName` instead of `.Name`:

```
Public Function IsFormVisible(FrmName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Frm As UserForm
'On Error GoTo errorH
    IsFormVisible = False
    For Each Frm In VBA.UserForms
        If lcase$(TypeName(Frm)) = lcase$(FrmName) Then
           IsFormVisible = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
errorH:
    IsFormVisible = False
End Function
```

I've made both of these case insensitive.

Comment: @Storax I think you got hung up on the function name. The question itself explicitly asks if the form is **loaded** or not.

Comment: Right, sorry, the function name **distracted** me. I will delete my answer and comments

Comment: @Storax I'd leave it there as it's a useful addition for future readers?

Comment: Sorry again at least for the comments. I could undelete my answer and explicitly mention that I got distracted by the function name.

Comment: @Storax Don't worry. I think it's useful as it points out what a misleading function name that is! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the code for `IsFormVisible` just misses one line of code if you really need to test for visibility.

**HINT** The question is as Rory pointed out rightfully about whether a userform is loaded or not. And for this question his answer is absolutely right.

```
Public Function IsFormVisibleA(FrmName As String) As Boolean
Dim Frm As Object
    On Error GoTo errorH
    IsFormVisibleA = False
    For Each Frm In VBA.UserForms
        If LCase$(Frm.Name) = LCase$(FrmName) Then
            If Frm.Visible Then
                IsFormVisibleA = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
errorH:
    IsFormVisibleA = False
End Function
```

You can test it like that. If you only load the form without showing it the function IsFormVisible will return true although the form is not visible.

```
    Sub Testfrm()
    Dim Frm As frmMy

        Set Frm = New frmMy
'        Frm.Show vbModeless

        Debug.Print Frm.Name
        Debug.Print IsFormVisibleA("frmMy"), IsFormVisible("frmMy")


    End Sub
```

Comment: My Concern was if loaded or not. Anyway, thanks for the addition.

Comment: As Rory said I got distracted by the function name. Maybe it's a good idea to rename the function to `isFormLoaded`

Answer (score 1):

"I want to check if a userform is loaded or not while running a code." was the question.

In VBA Excel if you check if the form is visible

```
If Form2.Visible Then
    'code here
End If
```

then the form will background load!
Not good if the loading process takes a long time!
so
best solution is

```
Function IsTheFormLoaded(frmName As String)
    'Works for VBA Excel office Xp 2002
    'Returns true if found or false if not found
    Dim Frm 'As UserForm dont declare as UserForm you wont get the frm.Name proptery below
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Found = False
    For Each Frm In VBA.UserForms
      If frmName = Frm.Name Then
         Found = True
         Exit For
      End If
    Next
     IsTheFormLoaded = Found
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Yes the acceptable solution is the same answer. Thanks anyway.