# Any explicit way to specify using vba functions?

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question. Is there any way to explicitly note that I want to use the excel VBA function instead of the user defined one.

For example in my scenario, I have this basic function,

```
Function Month(myMonth, myMonthText)
    Select Case myMonth
        Case "Jan"
            myMonthText = "January"
        Case "Feb"
            myMonthText = "February"
        Case "Mar"
            myMonthText = "March"
        Case "Apr"
            myMonthText = "April"
        Case "May"
            myMonthText = "May"
        Case "Jun"
            myMonthText = "June"
        Case "Jul"
            myMonthText = "July"
        Case "Aug"
            myMonthText = "August"
        Case "Sep"
            myMonthText = "September"
        Case "Oct"
            myMonthText = "October"
        Case "Nov"
            myMonthText = "November"
        Case "Dec"
            myMonthText = "December"
        Case Else
            myMonthText = "Error"
    End Select
End Function
```

The function is defined with the name "Month". VBA has its own Month function which returns the number value of the months instead. If there is a user defined function with names that overlap existing vba functions, how do I explicitly tell that I want to use the existing VBA function.

I know I can just rename the user defined function so that it does not overlap with the VBA functions and all would work out well, but would like to know if there is a way to get it to work in this type of scenario.

Comment: `VBA.Month` should do it

Comment: Ah yes. Very nice. Knew it was something really simple. Thanks.

Comment: Storax is right. But beside this: If you don't want to fool you or anyone that ever needs to touch your code: **Rename your function**!!

Comment: @MelBee: FunThomas is absolutely right. Even in cases you do not overlap choose function names carefully. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818343/vba-check-if-a-particular-userform-is-loaded-or-not/52818917#52818917) where I got distracted by the function name the OP chose.

Comment: @MelBee If you were in my dev team and name a function in VBA `Month` your survival chances would be very poor. And I mean very, very poor! A Mob of devs with pitchforks would be seen in the corridor. • If you don't like that scenario rename your function please.

Comment: @MelBee - side note: think you are generally misinterpreting the (pointless) parameter `myMonthText` as variable capable to 
return the function result. - You'd have to omit the 2nd argument and assign the result directly to a function's name instead; 
using the same very *risky* name as in OP you would have to state `Month = myMonthText` in the last code line before `End Function`. 
Furthermore you should at least declare the function's own data type returning only a string here and *`Dim`* the variable `myMonthText As String` (e.g. `Function Month(byVal myMonth As Variant) As String`).

Comment: Thank you all for the heads up! The code snippet was from a fellow co-worker which was written a few years ago. Had to add features to an existing macro and I just happened to come across such scenario. Did not want to fiddle around with the previous set of code. I will definitely select function names that do not crossover with existing vba functions and will always keep that in mind! Thank you guys.

Comment: Sorry to put you in a bad situation with open a new question. Hopefully my answer might help you :)!! Best wishes // W